# ⌘+L shortcut not working in Chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

Quite frequently I experience cases, where the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut will not work in Chrome.

This shortcut does the same in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. It jumps to the URL bar of the browser.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several postings on the Chromium issue tracker, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25756) and [this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98370), suggest that this is because some plugins (such as Flash) are consuming the keystrokes whilst running. Does this happen whilst Flash is running, or can you pinpoint an occasion when it always happens if a certain plugin is loaded?

Comment: Thanks! I assume you're right. The websites that I've experienced this problem with were using flash to display content. Is it possible to not make Chrome's flash consume the keystrokes?

Comment: Not sure, I'm afraid. It looks as though that's expected behaviour. If the plugins, like Flash, get first look at keystrokes they can presumably decide to consume or ignore. If Chromium were to fix it (so that Chrome itself got first look) then this might alter the behaviour of plugins that expected it, or they might never get certain keystrokes at all. The first link I posted has some discussion on what the "correct" course of action might be.

Answer (score 3):

Using something like fastscripts, override the shortcut of your liking.

An app like fastscripts listens globally (overrides both flash and chrome) but will act locally. It will do exactly what you want in this case.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "File"
                tell menu "File"
                    click menu item "Open Location…"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to deselect (exit) the Flash element.  Once exited, the element should no longer capture your key-presses, so <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> should work again!